# Overloading hash access to read/write to a database

Tags: database, perl, hash, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a very simple syntax to read and write to a database using Perl.  Basically the end goal is to be able to access fields in the database as if they were a simple Perl hash.

> *Unfortunately the type of database I am trying to access and its API are proprietary so I can't get into to much detail on how to actually read and write the data, just assume that the database name is enough information to connect. What needs to be done in Perl to make this work is pretty generic so API information should not be relevant.*

To start I am creating a simple database object:

```
my $database = Database->new('NAME');
```

Then I want to read from the database given a field name that I want to read:

```
# Read from the database
my $value = $database{'field_name'};

# Write to the database
$database{'field_name'} = $value;
```

---

Every time data is read from the hash I want it to call a function to query the database and get the value.

Every time data is written to the hash I want it to call a function to write the data to the database.

---

This is what I have so far:

**Database.pm**

```
package Database;

use overload '%{}' => \&access_data;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $name  = shift;

    my $self = bless {
        name => $name
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub access_data {
    my $self  = shift;
    my $field = shift;
    my $data  = shift;

    if (defined $data) {
        # Write data to the database using the database API
    }
    else {
        # Read data from the database using the database API
    }

    # Not sure what to return to make this work
}
```

**test.pl**

```
use Database;

my $database = Database->new('TESTDB');

# Overloaded to read the actual value from the database
print $database{'field_name'};
```

I have been searching through the documentation for [overloading hash access](https://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Two-face-References) but I am struggling to understand exactly how it works.

How can I get this kind of overloading to work the way that I want?

Comment: Your design doesn't account for the way regular SQL databases are organized. A single database can have many *tables*, each of which may  have multiple *columns* and multiple *rows*. You haven't provided a way to select a table, or to return multiple rows of a given column.

Comment: This isn't an SQL database. All of the info needed to grab a value from the database is the field name and a subscript. I left the subscript part off for this question though to simplify things. The end goal is to have syntax that looks like this `$val = $db{'field_name'}[1]` where `1` is the subscript of the desired record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to look at overloading, you want to look at tied variables. With a tied variable you can change the behaviour of a standard Perl variable so that accessing the variable can do things that the standard variables can't.

It's a bit hard to explain in an answer, but the [perltie](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) documentation is pretty clear.

Basically, you define your own package (which you might call Tie::Hash::Database). You then need to define a `TIEHASH()` method (which is the equivalent of a constructor) and methods (called things like `FETCH()`) for any of the operations you want to change. In pseudo-code (because I don't know how your database works) it might look a bit like this:

```
package Tie::Hash::Database;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Database;

sub TIEHASH {
  my $class = shift;
  my ($db_name) = @_;

  my $self = {
    db => Database->new($db_name);
  };

  return bless $self, $class;
}

# Store value in the hash
sub STORE {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($key, $val) = @_;

  # code to store the key/value pair in the database;
  $self->{db}->store($key, $value);
}

# Get value from hash
sub FETCH {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($key) = @_;

  # code to get value from the database
  return $self->{db}->get($key);
}

# ... etc ...
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
use Tie::Hash::Database;

my %db_hash;
tie %db_hash, 'Tie::Hash::Database', 'name_of_database';

$db_hash{some_key} = 'some value';

print $db_hash{some_key};
```

Many years ago I wrote an [article that explains all of this](https://perlhacks.com/articles/perl-com/changing-hash-behaviour-with-tie/) in more detail. You might find it useful.

**Update:** It's also worth pointing out that the standard Perl distribution comes with [tied hash support for various DBM files](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyDBM_File) (which are, effectively, binary files for the storage of persistent hashes).